# Engineer searching for calculus and complex analysis books without limits

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, reference-request, applications

I am an engineer and I need to study calculus and complex analysis without too much limits or Riemann sums or proofs. I mean on the differentiation and integration levels and higher (not digging downwards for proofs), with emphasis on geometric and physical interpretations (meanings) and applications. What books do you suggest?

By the way I heard that calculus and infinitesimals where used before the formal precise definition was invented latter. Does a book of that era can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Analysis-Applications-Engineering-Mathematics/dp/0139078746) might be a good bet for you; I used this as an undergrad.

Comment: I don't think it would be very helpful to use a book from before the 1850s, since the nonmathematical language might be a fairly significant barrier.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks I read the description on amazon just now and I really need it for signal processing and AC Circuit analysis..i didn't see the text yet but if it looks like the description withh less rigor it will be amazing .. thanks alot

Comment: @EricStucky thnx for ur help about the language of mathematics

Comment: A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John L Bell.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible to avoid limits if you want to do anything meaningful in complex analysis.

For one, the notion of differentiability in complex analysis is, although conceptually equivalent, mechanically different when analyzing complex functions. There's not really a notion of "symbolic differentiation." For example, take an arbitrary polynomial $P(z)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. This polynomial is almost surely **not** differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$. Functions in $\mathbb{C}$ that are differentiable are also *analytic* and *holomorphic*. These are important concepts; at least with analyticity, you get a real-valued analogue in that an analytic function has a Taylor series that converges.

Likewise, integration takes on a somewhat different meaning. In $\mathbb{C}$, we concern ourselves predominantly with contour integration. Functions in $\mathbb{C}$ become interesting to integrate when they have singularities, i.e. they are analytic everywhere except at some number of points. Contour integration serves as the fundamental basis for the interesting engineering applications pf complex analysis: the Fourier transform and the Laplace transform, for instance, are just contour integrals.

However, it's nearly impossible to approach these ideas mechanically. The important theorems all involve convergence of infinite sums and limits. Arguably the most powerful contour integration tool, the Residue Theorem, states that a contour integral of a function analytic everywhere on a domain except at poles is equal to the sum of the residues on those poles. And residues themselves are defined as limits! We cannot get away from this concept.

The basic cases that you may encounter in traditional engineering applications are summarized nicely in Shaum's Outline of Complex Variables. But you won't really understand the field; at best, you'll simply memorize a technique that only works for a handful of toy problems.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me.. but honestly I say am not a mathematician am an engineering student so I couldn't get some of ur terminology...but It's obvious u Understand this field well so pls I'd like to ask u : am going to study signal processing which include fourrier transform laplace transform and z-transform conformal mapping and dealing with complex numbers too much so what books+(sequence of reading) should i follow to have good understanding of complex analysis...do u suggest theory then applications or applications at first.. thnx

Comment: @Eng_Boody: To add to what Arkamis said, I think it would be a good idea to visit a university library or a good university bookstore, if possible, and then look at the many books in the Schaum's Outline Series (especially those by Murray R. Spiegel). When I was an undergraduate (late 1970s) I recall these being like extended "Cliff Notes" for the engineering students. See also the suggestions at the math StackExchange question [Problems and Resources to self-study medium level math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177485/problems-and-resources-to-self-study-medium-level-math).